# Loading files to RAM (static) for improving the read time

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file-io, buffer, ram

I am writing a C program for a small application where I need to read huge data from a file into a buffer and I need to do some mathematical operations on this data in the buffer. Problem is that, lets assume I have a file of size around 7MB, the reading values from this buffer is taking much time thereby degrading the performance of my application. Is it possible to write my file data into the RAM to get better performance by reducing the read operation from the buffer?

Comment: Yes, it can be possible. It's of course very hard to be more specific than so without seeing your code, for instance.

Comment: If it is taking a lot of time to read from buffer, maybe you should take a look at some sorting algorithms and some search algorithms.

Comment: As the file contains random int16 values there is no point of using any sorting algorithm.After reading this int16 values into a buffer every time I need to read a set of consecutive hundred values and do some mathematical operation with this values and it will continue in a loop till there are no more values in the buffer.

Comment: Could you please explain,how it will help in improving the read operation?

Comment: @Jaga: I don't know if you can actually do this on windows, but if you have some `mmap`-equivalent, you can get the file loaded into memory. Once it's memory-mapped, you have random-access into the file, and you don't need file-IO functions from the standard library any more. You can instead write your own functions, which will hopefully be better optimised for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pre-loading the file into memory can improve performance.  Here's the code to load a file given a `FILE *fpin`

```
size_t size = _filelength( _fileno( fpin ) );
void *buffer = malloc( size );
if ( !buffer || fread( buffer, 1, size, fpin ) != size )
{
    fprintf( "file load failed" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Edit - loop optimization

Try replacing this

```
for(i = index; i < (index+window_size); i++) 
{ sum+= buffer[i]; }
```

with this

```
unsigned short *bufptr = &buffer[index];
unsigned short *endptr = &buffer[index+window_size];
for ( ; bufptr < endptr; bufptr++ ) 
    sum += *bufptr;
```

Comment: I want to improve performance by reducing read operation from "buffer".Even after doing this and profiling it I observed that reading time from the buffer is nothing changed!

Comment: Ok, so file access isn't the bottleneck.  You mention reading a hundred values and performing a mathematical operation.  Without knowing what the mathematical operations are, it's not possible to suggest optimizations.

Comment: unsigned short buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    //here reading values from file into buffer[]...


    //mathematical operation on that buffer

    float doMath(int index, int window_size)
    {
    int i, j;
    float  ax_new , ax_prev, sum, result;

    ax_new  = ((ax_prev*window_size) - buffer[index-1] +buffer[index+(window_size-1)]) / (window_size);
 
    for(i = index; i < (index+window_size); i++)
    {
    sum+= buffer[i];  
    }

    result = sum/ax_new;
    return result;
    }

Comment: inside doMath(), while caluclating fo ax_new,I am reading values from the buffer by giving index number and there it is taking too much time!

Comment: Updated answer with a suggestion for loop optimization.

Comment: It might also help to make `sum` a `uint64_t` instead of a `float`.  Floating point math is typically slower that integer math.  After the sum has been computed, you can cast the result into a float.

Answer (score 0):

Going a little different direction I'm going to suggest that you profile your application and see exactly where all the time is spent. With enough experience you can *sometimes* guess correctly but often the slow areas are non-intuitive. Guessing incorrectly means you spend time optimizing things that have little to no affect on the overall speed of your program.

My guess is that the loading time of your 7 MB file is not the primary issue here as on modern hardware file load times are much lower than you'd expect. For example, I quickly tested reading a 14 MB file and load times were around 6 ms. Assuming you are loading your file only once I wouldn't expect this to be an issue.

Depending on your version of VS2010 you can use the built-in profiling abilities. If not you can create your own simple profiling ability using the Windows [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Once you find what areas are the slowest then can you start to look at how to make them faster.